# TypeError: DAT is undefined when using DAT.gui() in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, dat.gui

I'm trying to use `DAT.gui` in my code to control camera on `three.js`

I include the following in `index.html`  file.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='../_libs/DAT.GUI.min.js'></script>
```

I make sure to get files from `build` folder

when I use the following code in `my.js` file

```
var gui = new DAT.GUI();
    gui.add(camera.position, 'x', -500,500).step(5);
    gui.add(camera.position, 'y', -500,500).step(5);
    gui.add(camera.position, 'z', 1000,5000).step(5);
```

I got the following error `TypeError: DAT is undefined`.
I also tried to use `dat.GUI` in small letters but still the same problem. It seems that the `my.js` can't reach the `DAT.GUI.min.js` but why can reach other files.

Comment: saffa did my anwser fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It suppose to be lower case like this..

```
var gui = new dat.GUI();
    gui.add(camera.position, 'x', -500,500).step(5);
    gui.add(camera.position, 'y', -500,500).step(5);
    gui.add(camera.position, 'z', 1000,5000).step(5);
```

Now in upper case Like you did :

```
var gui = new DAT.GUI();
    gui.add(camera.position, 'x', -500,500).step(5);
    gui.add(camera.position, 'y', -500,500).step(5);
    gui.add(camera.position, 'z', 1000,5000).step(5);
```

Thats why it said DAT is undefined. Hope this helped!

### EDIT

Um i just saw you tried dat lowercase.. Well the problem here is with minified javascript versions.. I really dont reccomend min.js... Can you try .js?

### EDIT2

Um so this time, can you check by formatting all your code like this:

```
var params = {
    z: 100
}

gui.add(params, 'z', -500, 500).step(5).onChange(function(value) {
    camera.position.z = value;
});
```

If that dosent work ill need to have a plunker.

Comment: Hi @ Amanuel Bogale I tried your Edit 2  but also the same problem DAT is undefiend. i even re install every thing and start from scratch but it is still the same problem. I will upload my project to plunker tonight. thank you very much for your help and time.

Comment: Can you give me your Plnkr when you upload it @safaa1978 ?

Comment: Hi @ Amanuel Bogale. the folowing link contains my code. `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B888Wucfmry2S0FubkNFaUxkOXc`

Answer (score 0):

I was just having the same issue, and realized that in my index.html file, I was sourcing the dat.gui library **after** my main javascript file. Moving the dat.gui script src to **before** my main.js script src fixed this.